# ?How to convert a two dimensional arc into a three dimensional dome

Tags: matrices, geometry

I have a one dimensional array of data which describes a two dimensional arc in x and y.

I want to create a three dimensional surface based on this arc, i.e. if you 'held' the arc in the middle and turned it through 180 degrees it would describe a domed surface.

I'm doing this in Matlab, so I need an algebraic method. The data for the arc is stored in a 1x512 array (e.g. arc = [0, 1, 2, 4, 8 ..... 8, 4, 2 , 1, 0] or similar), so the resultant data must fit into a 512x512 matrix.

I'm certain there's a trivial way to achieve this, possibly even a built in function in the software, however, I'd like to achieve this mathematically rather than programmatically, so that it's possible to demonstrate the mechanics of the operation. Sadly, my mathematical ability is a bit rusty at the moment.

Many thanks,

G

Comment: You'll have to be clearer. What do the numbers in the $1\times512$ array represent? What do you want to have in the $512\times512$ array?

Comment: OK, so as Andrew guessed below, the index of the array is the x-value, and the data stored in the array is the y-value. The data represents a correction to a spherical mirror. The problem I have is that the correction is determined by a function that acts on a single axis, based on the idea that the spherical mirror is symmetrical across the other axis. I need to apply the correction all across the mirror, not just a single meridian (nice word, thanks Andrew).

Answer (score 1):

If the point $(x, y)$ is revolved halfway about the $x$-axis, it sweeps the semicircle
$$
(x, y\cos\theta, y\sin\theta),\quad 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi.
$$
I'm guessing that your array index serves as $x$ and the array entry serves as $y$. I don't speak MATLAB, but it's not clear you need a $512 \times 512$ array: You need to store $512$ pairs $(y\cos\theta, y\sin\theta)$ for each "meridian" over the top of the dome.

Comment: Thanks. I need a 512x512 array because the data is a correction which must be applied to another 512x512 array.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else arrives here with a similar problem, I found a programmatical solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691956/cross-section-2d-data-of-symmetric-len-into-z-matrix-matlab-3d-plot-from-2d-cr

I'm not sure how it stacks up mathematically, but for my purposes it seems effective.